# Error while sending data from controller to view in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am sending data from controller to view in codeigniter, everything works fine until i pass a data that is $this->data['mustvisitedcities'].

This is the controller

```
public function index() {
    
    $this->data['ptype'] = "index";

    if($this->validlang){

        $slug = $this->uri->segment(3);

    }else{

        $slug = $this->uri->segment(2);
    }

    if (!empty ($slug)) {

        $this->dests_lib->set_destid($slug);
        $this->data['details'] = $this->dests_lib->dest_details();
        $this->data['title'] = $this->dests_lib->title;
        $this->data['thumbnail'] = $this->dests_lib->thumbnail;
        $this->data['date'] = $this->dests_lib->date;

        $res = $this->Settings_model->get_contact_page_details();

        $this->data['phone'] = $res[0]->contact_phone;

        $this->data['langurl'] = base_url()."destinations/{langid}/".$this->dests_lib->slug;
        $mustvisitedlocid = $this->data['details'][0]->related_cities;

        
        $this->data['mustvisitedcities'] = $this->dests_lib->get_mustvisitedcity($mustvisitedlocid);

        $this->setMetaData($this->data['details'][0]->location_meta_title,$this->data['details'][0]->location_meta_desc,$this->data['details'][0]->location_meta_keywords);


        $this->theme->view('modules/destinations/dest_details', $this->data, $this);

    }
    else {
        $this->listing();
    }      
   
    
}
```

problem is passing $this->data['mustvisitedcities'] throw some error that i am not able to find. when i remove this then everything works fine.

I tried to print this variable and data is there as i want but its just impossible for me to pass this to view.

when i print  $this->data['mustvisitedcities'], i get following result

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2642 [location] => Irkutsk [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Irkutsk [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3067 [location] => Krasnojarsk [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Krasnojarsk [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3554 [location] => Saint Petersburg [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Saint Petersburg [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4081 [location] => Murmansk [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Murmansk [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4131 [location] => Moscow [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Moscow [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) )
```

in view i am fetching above data as

```
       <?php foreach($mustvisitedcities as $item){ ?>
    <div>
    <div>
      <a href="<?php echo $item->slug;?>">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="lazyload-wrapper">
              <img src="<?php echo $item->thumbnail;?>" alt="<?php echo character_limiter($item->location,30);?>" data-pin-nopin="true">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 color="#121416"><?php echo character_limiter($item->location,30);?></h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

When i print entire $this->data, i get this

```
Array ( [ptype] => index [details] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 9416 [country] => Russia [location] => Russia [location_slug] => [location_desc] => [location_meta_title] => Russia [location_meta_keywords] => [location_meta_desc] => [location_img] => [location_thumb] => 502844_russian.jpg [related_cities] => 2642,3067,3554,4081,4131 [preferred_cities] => [latitude] => 61.5240 [longitude] => 105.3188 [user] => [status] => Yes ) ) [title] => Russia [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/502844_russian.jpg [date] => [phone] => +918860709211 [langurl] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/{langid}/Russia [mustvisitedcities] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2642 [location] => Irkutsk [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Irkutsk [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3067 [location] => Krasnojarsk [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Krasnojarsk [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3554 [location] => Saint Petersburg [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Saint Petersburg [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4081 [location] => Murmansk [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Murmansk [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4131 [location] => Moscow [slug] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/destinations/Moscow [thumbnail] => https://www.happyvoyaging.com/uploads/images/locations/thumbs/ ) ) [pageTitle] => Russia [metadescription] => Book sightseeing tours, attractions, visa and experiences in 500+ destinations at guaranteed low prices with handpicked reliable suppliers. [metakeywords] => Tours, Sightseeing and Things To Do around the World, Russia Visa agent in India, Russia Visa agent Delhi, Dubai Visa agent Delhi, Dubai Visa agent India )
```

Comment: What is the error message when you pass the problematic data?

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

$data[‘variablename’] = $examplevariable;
$data[‘variablename2’] = “This is a test”;

$this->load->view(‘phpname’, $data);

To call it on view :